# SQLite sub query sum of column in where clause

Tags: android, sqlite, subquery

I'm querying database to get a cursor of values within last 24 hours entered. I can query and get all the values of the A_VALUE column I want, but I can't figure out how or where to correctly write the sub query to get the sum of the A_VALUE column with the where clause parameters and get its value. Any thoughts would be appreciated. (have zero coding background and I'm learning everything from this site and others)

//Current code to get values in last 24 hours is :

```
String[] projection = {
            DrinkContract.DrinkEntry._ID,
            DrinkContract.DrinkEntry.COLUMN_A_VALUE,
            DrinkContract.DrinkEntry.COLUMN_TIME_DATE};

    //code to query databse for last 24 hours

    String selection = DrinkContract.DrinkEntry.COLUMN_TIME_DATE + " BETWEEN strftime('%s', 'now', '-1 day') AND strftime('%s','now') ";

    Cursor dayCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            DrinkContract.DrinkEntry.CONTENT_URI,   // Provider content URI to query
            projection,             // Columns to include in the resulting Cursor
            selection,                   // selection clause
            null,
            DrinkContract.DrinkEntry.COLUMN_TIME_DATE); // Default sort order*/

    if (dayCursor == null || dayCursor.getCount() < 1) {
        return;
    }

    // Proceed with moving to the first row of the cursor and reading data from it

    while (dayCursor.moveToNext()) {

        int aValueColumnIndex = dayCursor.getColumnIndex(DrinkContract.DrinkEntry.COLUMN_A_VALUE);
        int drinkTimeDateColumnIndex = dayCursor.getColumnIndex(DrinkContract.DrinkEntry.COLUMN_TIME_DATE);

        // Extract out the value from the Cursor for the given column index
        double aValue = dayCursor.getDouble(aValueColumnIndex);


        System.out.println("The total a value is " + aValue);
```

Comment: A sum is a single value, and is computed from multiple rows. What should the value of the other two columns in your query be?

Comment: I don't need the sum from the other columns. From what I've read it should be as simple as adding sum(DrinkContract.DrinkEntry.COLUMN_A_VALUE) or total(DrinkContract.DrinkEntry.COLUMN_A_VALUE) in the SELECT or WHERE clauses to get the sum or total of that specific column, but I can't seem to get any version of that working. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)

Comment: oh man. finally got it to work. Thanks CL for responding. My brain finally put 2 and 2 together. For anyone with same issues. I added this to the projection line :                                                                                  
 String[] projection = {

                DrinkContract.DrinkEntry._ID,
                DrinkContract.DrinkEntry.COLUMN_TIME_DATE,
                "total("+DrinkContract.DrinkEntry.COLUMN_A_VALUE+") AS totalA "}; and then queried the column total with this: int aValueColumnIndex = dayCursor.getColumnIndex("totalA");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//working code

```
 String[] projection = {
        DrinkContract.DrinkEntry._ID,
        DrinkContract.DrinkEntry.COLUMN_TIME_DATE,
            "total("+DrinkContract.DrinkEntry.COLUMN_A_VALUE+") AS totalA "};

//code to query databse for last 24 hours

String selection = DrinkContract.DrinkEntry.COLUMN_TIME_DATE + " BETWEEN strftime('%s', 'now', '-1 day') AND strftime('%s','now') ";

Cursor dayCursor = getContentResolver().query(
        DrinkContract.DrinkEntry.CONTENT_URI,   // Provider content URI to query
        projection,             // Columns to include in the resulting Cursor
        selection,                   // selection clause
        null,
        DrinkContract.DrinkEntry.COLUMN_TIME_DATE); // Default sort order*/

if (dayCursor == null || dayCursor.getCount() < 1) {
    return;
}

// Proceed with moving to the first row of the cursor and reading data from it

while (dayCursor.moveToNext()) {

   int aValueColumnIndex = dayCursor.getColumnIndex("totalA");
    int drinkTimeDateColumnIndex = dayCursor.getColumnIndex(DrinkContract.DrinkEntry.COLUMN_TIME_DATE);

    // Extract out the value from the Cursor for the given column index
    double aValue = dayCursor.getDouble(aValueColumnIndex);


    System.out.println("The total a value is " + aValue);
```